# Pass PHP variable using session or post

Tags: php, variables, session, post, session-variables

I'm trying to take a response from payment gateway and display selected results onto results page, "approved.php".  I need to pass variables from this code to "approved.php".  Any suggestions on how to code this using SESSION or POST?

```
        if ($_POST["check"] != "1")
            {}//do nothing
        if($response_array[3]=="This transaction has been approved.")
            {
        session_start ();
        $_SESSION[($response_array[7])] = $trans_id;
        echo '<script language="Javascript">';
        echo 'window.location="/approved.php"';
        echo '</script>';
            }
        else
            {
        echo '<script language="Javascript">';
        echo 'window.location="/declined.html';
        echo '</script>';
            }
```

Then on approved.php

```
session_start();
$trans_id = $_SESSION['trans_id'];
echo $trans_id;
```

This is not working.  I'm getting session already started errors on approved.php and no variables are being passed.  Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Line 6: you should not add brackets around your $_SESSION variable name.

Comment: @OleKristianAanensen Why not? It's not necessary, but it doesn't hurt anything.

Comment: @Barmar ok it doesn't hurt anything, but it still isn't good coding.

Comment: using header was causing session error

Comment: @GertB. I sometimes  use javascript for it too, e.g. when the headers were already sent

Comment: @ThomasLeu when you get "headers already sent, there is another problem in your code (spaces before php starting tag for example). using javaScript is working around mistakes.

Comment: @GertB. There is a whole dictionary of html before the php starting tag, why would this be a problem?

Comment: @ThomasLeu that would be the reason to get the headers already sent error... read the php manual on header()

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what your array $response_array looks like, but if it's 8th element is not the string "trans_id", this is the problem. Maybe you wanted:

```
$_SESSION['trans_id'] = $trans_id;
```

or

```
$_SESSION['trans_id'] = $response_array[7];
```

Answer (score 0):

According to your question your assignment should look like this:

```
$_SESSION['trans_id'] = $response_array[7];
```

although I would use POST to store your trans_id if it is only needed on accept.php

Comment: `$_POST` doesn't persist across redirects

Comment: How would you do this with POST?

Comment: Sam is correct! I answered as if I wrote the code and I would not use redirects so you are stuck with $_SESSION